# Keeping substrings in Pandas if they appear in a positive list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to delete a substring in a pandas dataframe and only keep those parts of the substring that appear in a positiv list.

I manage to do it the other way round: deleting all parts of the string that appear in a negative list.

```
df['Who'] = ['cute little bear', 'a quick brown fox', 'a bear and a fox']
negative_list = ['cute', 'little', 'a', 'quick', 'brown'. 'and']
positive_list = ['bear', 'fox']

for n in negative_list:
    df['Who'] = d['Who'].str.replace(n, '', re.IRNORECASE)
```

Now the results will be as expected:

```
df['Who'] = ['bear', 'fox', 'bear fox']
```

What I am looking for is a solution that I can keep only the strings appearing in the positive list instead of deleting a negative list which than would be miles long.

Comment: What about `df['Who'] = df['Who'].str.extract(r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(positive_list)), flags=re.I)`? Are all `positive_list` items alphanumeric?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't insist in a one line solution you could split the sentences into parts, keep only the valid words and put things together again:

```
extract = df['Who'].str.extractall('([^ ]+)')
ok = extract.isin(positive_list)[0].values
df['Who'] =  extract.loc[ok, :].groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is much less concise than the solution from Joerg (+1), but is easier to understand for me (because i had no  prior knowledge on the extractall pandas series function). It simply creates a new list when iterating and replaces the old one:

```
import pandas as pd

whoList=['cute little bear', 'a quick brown fox', 'a bear and a fox']
df=pd.DataFrame({'Who':whoList})
positive_list = ['bear', 'fox']

newStringList=[]
for who in whoList:
    newStringList.append('')
    for i in positive_list:        
        if i in who:
            newStringList[-1]=newStringList[-1]+i+" "   

df['Who']=newStringList
```